# why don't i get the out put for values of 'a' other than 1?

Tags: java, for-loop

why isn't the loop starting again with different value of a other than 1.

```java
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ForDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("ENTER A NUMBER: ");
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        int a;
        
        for(a=1 ;a<11;a=a+1)
        for(b=b;b<16;b=b+1)
        System.out.println(b + " * " + a + " = " + b*a);
    }
}
```

output:

> ENTER A NUMBER: 1
>
> 1 * 1 = 1
>
> 2 * 1 = 2
>
> 3 * 1 = 3
>
> 4 * 1 = 4
>
> 5 * 1 = 5
>
> 6 * 1 = 6
>
> 7 * 1 = 7
>
> 8 * 1 = 8
>
> 9 * 1 = 9
>
> 10 * 1 = 10
>
> 11 * 1 = 11
>
> 12 * 1 = 12
>
> 13 * 1 = 13
>
> 14 * 1 = 14 here it terminates!

required output:

> 1 * 1 = 1
>
> 2 * 1 = 2
>
> 3 * 1 = 3
>
> 4 * 1 = 4
>
> 5 * 1 = 5
>
> 6 * 1 = 6
>
> 7 * 1 = 7
>
> 8 * 1 = 8
>
> 9 * 1 = 9
>
> 10 * 1 = 10
>
> 11 * 1 = 11
>
> 12 * 1 = 12
>
> 13 * 1  = 13
>
> 14 * 1 = 14
>
> 15 * 1 = 15
>
> 1 * 2 = 2
>
> 2 * 2 = 4
>
> 3 * 2 = 6
>
> 4 * 2 = 8
>
> 5 * 2 = 10
>
> 6 * 2 = 12
>
> 7 * 2 = 14
>
> 8 * 2 = 16
>
> 9 * 2 = 18
>
> 10 * 2 = 20
>
> 11 * 2 = 22
>
> 12 * 2 = 24
>
> 13 * 2 = 26
>
> 14 * 2 = 28
>
> 15 * 2 = 30  and so on....

Comment: `b=b` in `for(b=b;b<16;b=b+1)`. Your 1st inner loop ends with `b=16`. then in next outer loop iteration, your inner loop `b` is 16, so condition `b<16` is false.

Comment: also whats the point of taking user input `b`? what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: He is taking input for his starting position.
And I would like to add one note here is please check your input before processing. Your input must be less than or equal to 15. Otherwise your code doesn't produce any output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply assign your input variable `(x)` at the starting of the inner loop as below will solve your problem.

Till now you were initialized `b` as the last value of the previous iteration that is why your inner loop is not executed after the first iteration.

```
public class Simple {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("ENTER A NUMBER: ");
        int x = sc.nextInt(); // take input as x

        for(int a=1 ;a<11;a++) {
            for (int b = x; b < 16; b = b + 1) { // initialize b with input variable(x)
                System.out.println(b + " * " + a + " = " + b * a);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing this: `b=b`. So do this:

```
for(a=1 ;a<11;a=a+1)
        for(b=1;b<16;b=b+1) // change here!!
        System.out.println(b + " * " + a + " = " + b*a);
```